# ClickEvent gets fired multiple times when clicked on item in large list in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on a media player app. I am using a `RecyclerView` to display all songs on my phone. I have about 700 of them on my phone.

Now, with a list of only 5 songs, everything works just fine, but as soon as the list gets a little longer and scrolling is needed:

When I click on a song, let's say number 100, on my `RecyclerView` list ( after scrolling to it) I have noticed that the click event gets fired up to 10 times before the song is actually played.

Another thing I have noticed is that with stop points, the media player is actually starting to play songs each time a stopping point is hit, then stops that song as I click continue and players yes another song UNTIL it has reached the actual song that I clicked on and then it plays that song.

To make this clearer:

Say I scroll down to song 400.
Now slowing down the app via stop points I now here the songs:
10, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400.

This also slows the performance of the app down more and more the further I click on something later in the list. It is absolutely baffling to me, what I am missing here. It is technically working, but without stop points, a few seconds pass until the right song is played. And with stop points, I might even be able to listen to the entire songs until it finally reached the right position.

This is my source code for the recycler view that gets a list containing all mp3 objects and then does its magic:

```
public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        public List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj;
        Context ctx;
        Activity act;
        MediaMetadataRetriever reader;
        DataBase db;
        List<SeekObj> seekObj;
        private static MP3object ObjectToBeSaved;
        private string OldURI;
        private bool FirstSaveOldURI = true;

        public PhotoAlbumAdapter(List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj, Context ctx, DataBase db, List<SeekObj> seekObj, Activity act)
        {
            this.mp3Obj = mp3Obj;
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.db = db;
            this.seekObj = seekObj;
            this.act = act;
            reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                        Inflate(Resource.Layout.CardView, parent, false);
            PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView);
            return vh;
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;

            reader.SetDataSource(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);
            string SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
            string ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);

            Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(ctx.Assets, "Baiti.ttf");
            vh.SongName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            vh.AristName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            vh.SongName.Text = SongName;
            vh.AristName.Text = ArtistName;

            vh.SongName.Click += delegate { ClickEvent(position, ArtistName, SongName); };
            vh.AristName.Click += delegate { ClickEvent(position, ArtistName, SongName); };
            //vh.lnContainer.Click += delegate { ClickEvent(position, ArtistName, SongName); };

        }

        private void ClickEvent(int position, string artist, string song)
        {
            Android.Net.Uri SongUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);

            if (FirstSaveOldURI) // this will happen ONLY once, otherwise wed catch one click too far 
            {
                OldURI = SongUri.ToString();
                FirstSaveOldURI = false;
            }
            Activity_Player.CurrentSongObject = WriteMetaDataToFileList(SongUri.ToString());
            Activity_Player.txt_CurrentSong.Text = song;
            Activity_Player.txt_CurrentArtist.Text = artist;
            PlayMusic(SongUri);
        }

        private void PlayMusic(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            ObjectToBeSaved = WriteMetaDataToFileList(OldURI);

            Activity_Player.firstStart = false;

            Activity_Player.txt_CurrentSong.Text = Activity_Player.CurrentSongObject.SongName;
            Activity_Player.txt_CurrentArtist.Text = Activity_Player.CurrentSongObject.ArtistName;


            if (Activity_Player.mediaPlayer.IsPlaying)
            {
                int currentPos = Activity_Player.mediaPlayer.CurrentPosition;
                WriteSeekingToDataBase(currentPos, ObjectToBeSaved); // FALSCHES OBJECT. EINS ZU WEIT 

                Activity_Player.mediaPlayer.Stop();
                Activity_Player.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(ctx, uri);

            }
            else
            {
                Activity_Player.mediaPlayer.Stop();
                Activity_Player.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(ctx, uri);
                Activity_Player.btn_StartOrPause.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_pause);

            }

            if (Activity_Player.specialMode)
            {
                SeekToSongMillis(uri.ToString());
            }

            StartMediaPlayer();
            Activity_Player.seekBar.Max = Activity_Player.mediaPlayer.Duration;
            Activity_Player.timer.Interval = 10;
            Activity_Player.timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            Activity_Player.timer.Enabled = true;

            Activity_Player.mediaPlayer.Completion += delegate
            {
                if (Activity_Player.rndMode)
                    ChooseRandomNewSongAndPlay(true);
                else
                {
                    ChoosesNonRandomNextSongAndPlay(true);
                }
            };

            OldURI = uri.ToString(); // last set the old uri
        }



        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return mp3Obj.Count(); }
        }










    } 
    public class PhotoViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
        public TextView SongName { get; private set; }
        public LinearLayout lnContainer { get; private set; }
        public TextView AristName { get; private set; }

        public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            // Locate and cache view references:
            SongName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
            AristName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            lnContainer = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_cardview);

            itemView.Click += delegate
            {


            };
        }
    }
```

I have left a few lines out to only focus on the important stuff, but clearly, something is wrong here.

Any help would be super awesome!

Thank you :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is that even Kotlin or Java?! That looks more like C# to me.

Comment: yes, it is c# ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `position` to get an mp3 track to play. It will provide an ambiguous result when u  select certain tracks in recycle views. Therefore, You can bind unique id or tag with the view when it attaching to recycle view. Then u can get that unique id by getting the clicked view from that recycle list

you can change  Signature of your Click event like below

```
  private void ClickEvent(View view,int position, string artist, string song)
```

pass view form `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` by overriding onclick event. Then get tag or unique id from view that u got like this `view.tag..` inside onclick event.

Comment: hey thanks. but how do i bind a unique id in my sample?